# Closed Testing 20 Testers Requirement?

Tags: android, google-play

I recently developed a gaming app and want to publish it on Play console
Do i need need 20 Testers for old play console account to publish gaming App?

Comment: If you have developer account created before Nov 13 2023, then you no need to have 20 testers to test in closed testing phase as per [this document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14151465?hl=en#:~:text=You%20must%20run%20a%20closed%20test%20before%20you%20can%20apply,finished%20setting%20up%20your%20app.) but this restriction may apply to older accounts to sooner or later.  But if you have developer account created after Nov 13 2023, then you have to have 20 testers in closed testing phase, they need to test your app for over the period of 14 days.